# Where does strīx come from?

Tags: etymology, ovidius, mythology

Ovid's *Fastī* for June 1 relates a story about *strīgēs*, witches who could transform into owls and magically sap the life of infants. There seem to be two forms of this word, *strīx, -gis* and *strīga, -ae*.

But where do these forms come from? Ovid suggests a connection to *strīdēre* "to screech", but that would require the D to turn into a G, so it sounds like folk etymology to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, “strix” and “striga” have not found their way into de Vaan’s etymological dictionary. The older dictionary by Walde does connect “strix” with “strideo”, tracing them back to an IE *strei- “to screech”, with two different extensions: -g and -d.

Comment: When a word is missing in de Vaan it's often because he thinks it's a loanword (which his dictionary excludes, for some reason) -- maybe that's the case with *strix*.

Comment: @TKR Possible: Wiktionary connects it to a putative Greek *_strinx_ but I can't find attestation of that anywhere.

Comment: @Draconis. http://www.zeno.org/Pape-1880/A/%CF%83%CF%84%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%B3%CE%BE

Comment: Walde cites this as a (potential) cognate, not as the source of a borrowing.